# Getting wrong data while using the Store API - List Subscriptions by Application - WSO2

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am following the below steps to get the subscriptions per application.

1. curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=random&password=random

Now logged in and got the cookie details.

2.curl -b cookies 'http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-list/ajax/subscription-list.jag?action=getSubscriptionByApplication&app=App1'

Now , I am getting the subscriptions for the application App1 which has subscriber by the user admin not random.

Why this API thorws admin subscription instead of the particular user even though we are posting the request with the use of cookies. Please help.

Comment: did you subscribe to App1 via user random?

Comment: Just a related note: Those APIs are now deprecated and new REST APIs are recommended. 
pub: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/publisher/
store: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/store/

Comment: Fazlan : Yes I have subscribed using App1 via user random..

Comment: @Bhathiya - I am using version 1.10.0. It should work right then.

Answer (score 1):

The following curl request will List all **API subscriptions** of App1.

**Request**

```
.curl -b cookies 'http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-list/ajax/subscription-list.jag?action=getSubscriptionByApplication&app=App1'
```

**Response**

```
{"error" : false, "apis" : [{"apiName" : "CalculatorAPI", "apiVersion" : "1.0", "apiProvider" : "admin", "description" : "Simple calculator API to perform addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.", "subscribedTier" : "Unlimited", "status" : "PUBLISHED", "subStatus" : "UNBLOCKED"}]}
```

The response does not have a field for **subscribedUsers**

Hence I assume what you saw as admin was the apiProvider.

Comment: Please try to login with diff users and subscribe the same API with different tier and then try the same . I am sure you will get only the above result with Tier as Unlimited not the one which you have subscribed with the new Tier. Note: Please subscribe it using App1for both users.